# VPN, can ping websites and telnet but can't access them

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm on ubuntu 18, and I'm using cisco vpn. I ignore routes that come from the server and I add them myself. This happens on both http and https. Not really sure where to look.

Seems like I can ping,telnet and when I do curl it throws this error:

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to domain.com ([ip]) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to domain.com:443 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided only barely enough information - but your description and symptoms point to an MTU issue - VPNs reduce the available bytes per packet, and the result is that sessions using smaller packets (like ping and interactive sessions) work, while sessions sending full packets break and freeze.

There are a number of possible solutions/wprk-arrounds - the easiest way to test the theory would be to set the MTU on your interfaces smaller (1476 bytes is typical). If that solves the problem for local connections to/from the box, try implement MTU clamping.

Comment: that doesn't seem to fix anything, I set it on 2k. I think it has something to do with the router maybe.

Comment: If you set it to 2k, its not surprising it did not do anything to fix the problem.  The figure needs to be less then 1500 which is the "standard/default" size - I would suggest trying 1476 - that number is not arbitrary.

Comment: It was set to 1426 or something like that before, I set it to 1476 same result.

Comment: Is your CISCO doing deal packet inspection?

Comment: not sure what that is. I got some free time finally, I will move my pc so I can connect it to the modem rather than the router, and check if that works

Comment: Yep it's the router. Don't know what the issue is though. Some people were suggesting portforwarding but I did on ports: 10000 4500 and 500, and it's still the same.